# Ebay product api consumer id error

Tags: python, python-requests, ebay-api

I'm trying to call "getProductDetails" from ebay Product API but I get the following error:

```
u'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><errorMessage xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/marketplacecatalog/v1/services">
 <error><errorId>2000</errorId><domain>CoreRuntime</domain><severity>Error</severity><category>Request</category>
 <message>Service operation  is unknown</message><subdomain>Inbound_Meta_Data</subdomain><parameter name="Param1">
 </parameter></error><error><errorId>9</errorId><domain>Marketplace</domain><severity>Error</severity><category>Application
 </category><message>Invalid CONSUMER-ID specified</message><subdomain>MarketplaceCommon</subdomain><parameter name="CONSUMER_ID"/>
 </error></errorMessage>'
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
target_url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/marketplacecatalog/ProductService/v1"
xml_request = """\    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getProductDetailsRequest 
xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/marketplacecatalog/v1/services">
   <productDetailsRequest>
      <productIdentifier>
         <productId>183439271</productId>
      </productIdentifier>
      <dataset>DisplayableProductDetails</dataset>
   </productDetailsRequest>
</getProductDetailsRequest> 
"""  

headers = {
    'OPERATION-NAME': 'getProductDetails',
    'SECURITY-APPNAME': APPID,
    } s

requests.post(target_url, data=xml_request, headers=headers).text
```

Edit: I don't have a Consumer-ID, the keys I've got from ebay are: appid, devid, certid and token. In the [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/product/Concepts/MakingACall.html#StandardURLParameters) there's no mention of a consumerid, only mentions the appid.

Comment: Well for one, your `xml_request` is not valid `xml`, you start the string with a slash

Comment: From the error message it appears to want a ConsumerID, from your request I can't see that one is being passed.

Comment: @Mathemats I edited the post to clarify your comment.

Answer (score 0):

God, I hate terrible Api documentation.  The different apis need different headers, urls, and xmlns, its really annoying.  Anyways, you're missing the 'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME' header which is called 'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME' for many of the other apis.  It takes in your app ID.

Comment: Can you provide a working example/template?